# Using AutoIT with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

In my previous question which was answered greatly, I was told how to interact with a website with selenium but unfortunately interacting with the flash game itself is now the problem. I have tried researching how to do it in Selenium but it can't be done. I've seen FlashSelenium, Sikuli, and AutoIT.

I can only find documentation for FlashSelenium in Java, It's easier for me to use AutoIT rather than Sikuli as I'd have to learn to use Jpython to create the kind of script I want to, which I am not straying away from learning just trying to finish this as fast as possible. As for AutoIT, the only problem with it is that I don't undertsand how to use it with selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import autoit
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://na58.evony.com/s.html?loginid=747970653D74727947616D65&adv=index")
driver.maximize_window()
assert "Evony - Free forever " in driver.title
```

So far I have this and It's doing what is suppose to do which is create a new account using that "driver.get" but when I reach to the page, it is all flash and I can not interact with anything in the webpage so I have to use AutoIT but I don't know how to get it to "pick-up" from where selenium left off. I want it to interact with a button on the webpage and from viewing a previous post on stackoverflow I can use a (x,y) to specify the location but unfortunately that post didn't explain beyond that. Any and all information would be great, thanks.